# Bitbucket custom branching

Tags: bitbucket

I need a suggestion as I have used Bitbucket as an end user only. Now it's time where I have to define a strategy for the team to use the specific code in a specific location.

Requirement:

1. There is common repo which has a common code
2. There are other repos like location1, Location2 which will have common + location-specific changes
3. Now, whenever we have the common issue it will get fixed in common repo and that change should propagate to location1 and location2 repo
4. Location-specific change should be fixed in that particular repo
5. Proper versioning and tagging should be in place

I can visualize the model but not sure how to get that in Bitbucket in theory.

Inputs are much appreciated. I am reading Bitbucket in parallel, so I don't have progress so far.

Comment: It sounds like location1, etc. would be forks of the common repo, and then you should be able to pull changes from common into the locations relatively easily. Would the versioning and tagging from common need to be passed to the locations as well?

Comment: Yes, the meta information is required